# SqlException: Invalid column name 'VendorsvendorId'.on EF Core. It Works on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

i have 2 separate projects, with exact same models.
The model runs ok on Entity Framework project and read the database:

```
List<ProductComponents> productComponents = new List<ProductComponents>();
productComponents = context.productComponents.ToList();
```

When i am trying to access the database from the other EF Core project i am getting this error: SqlException: Invalid column name 'VendorsvendorId'.

My 2 models:

```
public class ProductComponents 
{
    [Key]
    public int componentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? vendorId { get; set; } = 1;
    public Vendors Vendors { get; set; }
}

public class Vendors
{
    [Key]
    public int vendorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductComponents> ProductComponents { get; set; }
 }
```

```
return View(await _context.ProductComponents.ToListAsync());
```

please help me where to start looking! tried resetting migration, ForignKey annotation, no luck so far!`enter code here`

Comment: Start looking at EF core fluent api to configure your db model.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Comment: builder.Entity<ProductComponents>()
    .HasOne<Vendors>(s => s.Vendors)
    .WithMany(g => g.ProductComponents)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.vendorId);

Comment: any explanation why EF core was looking at column VendorsvendorId that did not exist in the table?

Comment: I would assume it would be a difference in conventions accepted by EF for default recognized table and key names. If you explicitly defined your table and PK column names in EF6 & EF Core it likely would have worked. When EF is left to try and determine the keys, the two version rules may differ. (Case sensitivity, pluralization, etc.) I don't like to ever rely on convention mainly because conventions can change. :)

Comment: This is because you have plural `public Vendor Vendors`, but your pk is not plural `int? vendorId` so you don't match the default conventions. I think if you either had `public Vendor Vendor` or `public int? vendorsId` it would have worked without fluent api config.